# Allow alternative values to be compared to an exiting list

Tags: python, regex, list, dictionary, substitution

I am trying to check if a word is in a list, but allow for replacements.

```
cars = [green_2door, Kelly_4door, ruby_2door]
car_colors = {}
colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'purple']
allowed_colors = {'red' : ['ruby', 'scarlet'],
             'blue' : ['azure', 'sapphire'],
             'green' : ['forest', 'kelly']}

words = cars.lower().split('_')
for word in words:
    if word in colors: 
        car_colors.append(word)
```

How would I go about allowing ruby to equate to red and add to the car_colors dict but still maintain it's original value?

I have been trying to use re.sub but am receiving an error.

```
regex = '|'.join(allowed_colors)

re.sub(regex, lambda x: allowed_colors[x.group()], colors)
```

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

```
re.sub(regex, allowed_colors, colors)
```

TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

are there alternatives?

Comment: There seems to be something missing in your regex question. Like where is the regex.

Comment: you're right, that got deleted regex = '|'.join(allowed_colors)

Comment: Except python this is an variable assignment of the results of a join ?

Comment: I'm brand new, but basically I want to check cars for their colors and if the color is ruby, allow that to be mapped to red.

Comment: Use a callback. Get all your changeable colors in an alternation `\b(red|blue|green)\b`. the matched color will be the _key_ into a hash where it's value will be used as the replacement. Ex. red->ruby. Search pythons sub() lambda callback methods. A single hash is all you need, don't over complicate it.

Answer (score -2):

I think what would help here is reversing your allowed_colors.
For example:
`allowed_colors = {'scarlet':'red', 'red':'red','kelly':'green'}` etc.

Then loop through allowed_colors.keys(). if you find a match, add the value corresponding to the key.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).